# Android: getting width available within layout

Tags: android, view, width

I'm wondering whether there is a way to find out the space available for Views within a layout.

To be a little more precise: in the activity two TextViews are displayed side by side. As the second one contains pretty much text, I'd like to check, whether this text can be displayed on the screen or whether it's too large. If that's the case I'll display a smaller version of the text instead (as Android doesn't display this text on multiple lines by default).
Currently I'm using some code like this:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point screenSize = new Point();
display.getSize(screenSize);
int screenWidth = screenSize.x;

if (tvTitle.getWidth() + tvDescription.getWidth() > screenWidth) {
    tvDescrition.setText(getString(R.string.descritption_short));
}
```

But this doesn't work: the widths normally are smaller than the screen, so the long version is used. But: the text isn't displayed completely, the last words are always missing.

I guess the problem is, that the layout is using a padding and is therefore reducing the space really available.

So how to fix this? Any ideas are extremely welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the width of a text(String) in pixels. Using this method:

[Paint.measureText(titleString + descriptionString);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29)

If that exceeds the total `screen width - horizontal margin - horizontal padding`  then you can go for the short description.

Comment: Thank you! Two questions appear to my mind:
why do you use `measureText` instead of `TextView.getWidth()`?
And how do I get the margin of an element?